# How to route class component by clicking button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-router

I am new to React. I am trying to build a page and having like 3 `button` or `img` on main page. When I click either one, I shall be routed to another class component. You can treat it like click the icon and route you to another category page (just an example). Below is my structure and partial code I tried. I have no idea how to achieve that, and I googled and seems cannot find the stuff I want.

Structure:

```
/src
  .index.js
  .App.js
  .BookStore.js
  .FruitStore.js
  .FoodStore.js
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

render(
    <App />, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import BookStore from "./BookStore";

const AppContainer = () => {
    return (
        //do the routing 
        <BookStore/>
    )
};

export default AppContainer;
```

BookStore.js

```
export default class BookStore extends React.Component {
}
const contentDiv = document.getElementById("root");
const gridProps = window.gridProps || {};
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(BookStore , gridProps), contentDiv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could have a look at the/one react router, e.g. https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

However, since you're writing you're new to react, this might be a little too much ...

First, I was wondering why you're using the "ReactDOM" in your indexjs (that seems to be correct), but also in the BookStore.js. I would also recommend to write your components as functions, like your "AppContainer" and not use the class components anymore (or do you really need to do that? - why?). You can use hooks instead to have e.g. state in the components.

You would then need any kind of state in your AppContainer which is used for the routing. Maybe like this:

```
const AppContainer = () => {
    const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = useState();
    return <>
        {!showDetail && <BookStore onDetail={detail => setShowDetail(detail)} />}
        {showDetail && <DetailPage detail={showDetail} onBack={() => setShowDetail(undefined)}}
    </>
}
```

Your AppContainer then has a state wheter or not to show the Bookstore (which is shown when "showDetail" is falsy, or a DetailPage which is shown when showDetail is truthy.

For this to work, your Bookstore needs to provide callbacks to let the AppContainer know that something should change. Very simply it could look like this:

```
const BookStore = ({onDetail}) => {
    return <button onClick={() => onDetail("anything")}>Click me</button>
}
```

Now when someone clicks the button on the bookstore, it calls the "onDetail" callback, which was set in the AppContainer to set the "showDetail" state. So this one will be updated to "anything" in this case. This will result in a rerender on the AppContainer which will now render a DetailPage component instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comprehensive explanation. But may I ask what should I use instead of ReactDom?

Comment: Besides, I use the class component is because I have lots of functions inside the class for fetching data. What will be a better approach to handle those "small function" if changing the component into function

Comment: Of course it's correct to use ReactDOM, but in general only once for your application, so in your index.js and nowhere else. After that, all components should be subcomponents of that one that you rendered with ReactDOM, but you've done it like this (at least as far as I can see). You just don't need it a second time, because it's only used to render the root component of your applicaiton into the dom.

Comment: Class components are the classic way of writing components. It's recommended by the react devs to use them: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-i-need-to-rewrite-all-my-class-components ... but as you can see, class components will be supported for the forseeable future. Some things seem to be easier to achive with class components, but the main reason for that is that you might be more used to the concepts. Once you learn to use hooks, they will  feeld equally natural to work with.

Comment: ... It's hard to answer your question without seeing that code ... these "small functions" you're talking about. Often you can just write them as normal functions besides your functional component. If they need the component state, you can just inline them in the functional component itself. I created a very small example in Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflowexample-t645k ... You can see that i used an inline function for fetching data that can access the component state.

Comment: Hi Reductio, I have tried something but still can't route successfully, would you mind helping to see what I missed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63393649/how-to-route-to-a-page-after-clicking-from-side-bar-in-react Thanks!