# How to route to a page after clicking from side-bar in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I am trying to build a `side-bar` with `ListItem` and route to a page after clicking it. Below is what I try. I have 2 class component in my `index` - one is `side menu` and one is the to-be-render component "depositLayout". Seems when I click it, the page cannot render the component and just the `url` changed. Am I missing something? Thanks so much for helping me out.

Code:

index.js:

```
function App(props){
  
  return(
    <AppBar />
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/deposit" exact component={depositLayout}></Route>
          <Route path="/"></Route>
        </Switch>
       </div>
  )  
}
const contentDiv = document.getElementById("root");
const gridProps = window.gridProps || {};
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, gridProps), contentDiv);
```

AppBar.js

```
class AppBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <SideBar></SideBar>
  );
}
export default AppBar;
```

SideBar.js

```
class SideBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
      popSideBar: false,
  };
  //some control sidebar behavior

  sideBarItem = item =>(
    <div>
      <List>
        <ListItem button key={'deposit'} component={Link} to="/deposit">
          <ListItemText primary={'Bank'}/>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </div>
  );
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Router>
        <SwipeableDrawer>
          {this.sideBarItem ('popSideBar')}
        </SwipeableDrawer>
      </Router>
    );  
  }
}
export default SideBar ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I right got your problem, try to change this part

```
 sideBarItem = item =>{
   return(
    <div>
      <List>
        <ListItem button key={'deposit'} component={Link} to="/deposit">
          <ListItemText primary={'Bank'}/>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </div>
   )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your direction is right. I found that when I click the sidebar, it only render itself but not the whole page. But there is error when I add return.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing the "BrowserRouter" (often imported as "Router") component in your index.js:

```
import BrowserRouter as Router;

function App(props){
  return(
    <Router>
        <AppBar />
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/deposit" exact component={depositLayout}></Route>
                <Route path="/"></Route>
            </Switch>
       </div>
   </Router>)  
}
```